# Security checking in meta_box save is reluctant?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox, security, nonce

For example, in [this tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/), the code suggested when saving meta box data is

```
/* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
if ( !isset( $_POST['smashing_post_class_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['smashing_post_class_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return $post_id;

/* Get the post type object. */
$post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

/* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;
```

The checking of `nonce` and `user role` seems reluctant, seems they hook into the `save_post`, which is almost the last line in the function `wp_insert_post`, WordPress should already performed the needed checks, right?

So I can safely remove them?

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, but just for clarification, do you mean "redundant" instead of "reluctant"?

Answer (score 4):

No, not really. You're assuming the function that called `wp_insert_post()` has already performed those checks. But `wp_insert_post()` may be used in other pages too, not just the edit page, by plugins, or even themes (many of them with security holes).

That's why you should ensure that your code runs only where you want to by using the nonce.

---

Ok I'm editing the answer because the comment reply would be too long.

> If a plugin expose wp_insert_post, it is not only my new
>   custom field will be hacked, it is all the post fields will get
>   hacked. (again, this is the bug in plugin) So, I really can't see
>   verifying my own custom field can bring any additional security

But it would get "hacked" with the help of your code. Think about the quick post form on dashboard home. It doesn't have input fields for your post meta, does it? On submission, `wp_insert_post` -> `save_post` gets called and if `$_POST` contains your meta fields (it's easy to edit the source and add some), they will get saved by your meta box code. Essentially, if you don't do nonce checks, your making it possible to change your meta fields from any form in WordPress that involves post editing, not just the one to which you attached your custom input fields. Is this what you want?

> I am NOT creating a new action, so if the core wordpress's code allow
>   calling wp_insert_post without verifying the nonce, this is a bug in
>   WP. (As you can see they all called the check_admin_referer in the
>   post.php.

The purpose of `wp_insert_post` is to insert posts, not to check from where the data comes from. However I do agree that the `save_post` action was badly placed. Such functions should not fire actions and filters at all. Instead the action should have been fired by each form submission handler. Besides the fact that this action introduces more inconsistencies in the WP API, it also facilitates exploits...

Comment: @OneTrickPony, I think in this way: I am NOT creating a new action, so if the core wordpress's code allow calling `wp_insert_post` without verifying the nonce, this is a bug in WP. (As you can see they all called the `check_admin_referer` in the `post.php`. If a plugin expose `wp_insert_post`, it is not only my new custom field will be hacked, it is all the post fields will get hacked. (again, this is the bug in plugin) So, I really can't see verifying my own custom field can bring any additional security.

Comment: @Yoga: I added the reply in my A

Comment: Thanks. My reply to your question: " Essentially, if you don't do nonce checks, your making it possible to change your meta fields" Yes, but does it matter? WP already checked the user has permission to update the post, so even the user hacked to update the meta in the quick post form, they hack their own data and why bother? If this is important, WP should already using one nonce per field, not per form.

Comment: The quick post form was just an example. There are plugins out there which can call `wp_insert_post` on visitor actions, to update post views, or ratings etc.